# PHP Multi dimensional array using for within for to echo a string

Tags: php, arrays

Just ran into a wall here and would much appreciate if anybody could help clear this issue out.

Just in case anybody is wondering what I am trying to accomplish, I am currently practicing PHP so the block of code below is not something I'm trying to use for a website.

I am trying to join `$cars[0][0]` with `$cars[1][0]` to to make a string that says:

```
"A cool car is the Ferrari F458 Super Car"
```

and have it jump to the next string which would be `$cars[0][1]` and `$cars[1][1]` and so on till the `echo` runs the full `$length` of the array items.

With the below code, the result which is currently being displayed is:

```
echo "A cool car is the " . $cars[0][0] . " " . $cars[1][0] . " Super Car<br />";
```

This repeats for 6 lines and then jumps to next array item `[0][1]` and `[1][1]` repeats another 6 lines.

I am trying to get them to echo 1 line and go onto the next, have tried separating the `echo` and writing `for($a)` with `echo` and `for($b)` line after with the remainder of the `echo`, but that turned out to be way worse. I tried a few other iterations but some were just invalid. Tried looking for anything online, but couldn't find anything this specific. The best result I have been able to achieve is that it repeats the same string 6 times then moves onto the `+1`.

Note: I've been able to accomplish this on another practice session using associative arrays, but for the sake of this practice session, I'm trying to accomplish it without using associative arrays just to better my understanding of using integers.

```
<?php //Echoing arrays using integers standard method
$cars = array(array("Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Aston Martin", "Mercedes",   "Maserati", "McLaren"), array("F458", "Aventador", "one-77", "GT", "GTS", "MP4-12C"));
$lengthOne = count($cars[0]);
$lengthTwo = count($cars[1]);
for($a = 0; $a < $lengthOne; $a++) {
    for($b = 0; $b < $lengthTwo; $b++) {
        echo "A cool car is the " . $cars[0][$a] . " " . $cars[1][$b] . " Super Car<br />";
    }
}
?>
<?php
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated!!

Edit: `$b` is now `< $lengthTwo`  (Still same result though)

Edit: changed `$cars[1][$a]` to `[1][$b]` (Results are even more jumbled now)

Comment: I just tried this as well, seems to be invalid.
    for($a = 0, $b = 0; $a < $lengthOne, $b < $lengthTwo; $a++, $b++) {
                    echo "A cool car is the " . $cars[0][$a] . " " . $cars[1][$a] . " Super Car<br />";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single loop and use the same index for both sub-arrays:

Code:

```
<?php

  $cars = array(
    array("Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "Aston Martin", "Mercedes",   "Maserati", "McLaren"), 
    array("F458", "Aventador", "one-77", "GT", "GTS", "MP4-12C")
  );
  $length = min (count ($cars[0]), count ($cars[1]));  /* In case the arrays have different lengths. */
  for($a = 0; $a < $length; $a++) {
    echo "A cool car is the " . $cars[0][$a] . " " . $cars[1][$a] . " Super Car\n";
  }
```

Output:

```
A cool car is the Ferrari F458 Super Car
A cool car is the Lamborghini Aventador Super Car
A cool car is the Aston Martin one-77 Super Car
A cool car is the Mercedes GT Super Car
A cool car is the Maserati GTS Super Car
A cool car is the McLaren MP4-12C Super Car
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$cars = array(
   array("Ferrari","Lamborghini","Aston Martin","Mercedes","Maserati","McLaren"),
   array("F458","Aventador","one-77","GT","GTS","MP4-12C")
);

foreach($cars[0] as $key => $value)
{
    if (isset($cars[1][$key]))
      echo "A cool car is the ".$value." ".$cars[1][$key]." Super Car.\n";
}
```

Comment: Hey Cheery, your code was also valid, I would like to atleast give a +1 to your answer but i don't have enough rep yet. Also i had to give the correct answer to Nisse because he replied just before you and his answer was also right!

Big thanks though, much appreciated Cheery!

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment, but I still have not 50 rep...

The second bucle defines $b, but you don't use it anywhere, so the data showed in the second bucle is the same each time it runs.

EDIT: You neither use "$lengthTwo" anywhere.

Comment: Hi Desaroll, ohh yeah that was something i tried to see if it would work, but essentially $lengthOne and $lengthTwo both are 6, so using one or the other seemed not pull same results. Nice for checking that out though, i will make the edit.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of learning :) another four ways of approaching the same issue:

#### each method

```
reset($cars[0]);
reset($cars[1]);

while( ($brand=each($cars[0])) && 
       ($name=each($cars[1])) ) {
    echo "A cool car is the {$brand[value]} {$name[value]} Super Car<br />\n";
}
```

#### next method

```
$brand = reset($cars[0]);
$name = reset($cars[1]);

do {
  echo "A cool car is the $brand $name Super Car<br />\n";
} while ( ($brand=next($cars[0])) && ($name=next($cars[1])) );
```

#### array_combine method:

```
$cars_combined = array_combine($cars[0], $cars[1]);
foreach ( $cars_combined as $brand => $name ) {
  echo "A cool car is the $brand $name Super Car<br />\n";
}
```

#### array_walk method:

```
array_walk($cars[0], function($brand, $key){
    global $cars;
    echo "A cool car is the {$brand} {$cars[1][$key]} Super Car<br />\n";
});
```

As pointed out by Cheery, as of 5.3, the [use operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) should be used, rather than `global`. Which is definitely neater to say the least.

```
array_walk($cars[0], function($brand, $key) use($cars) {
    echo "A cool car is the {$brand} {$cars[1][$key]} Super Car<br />\n";
});
```

Comment: As of php 5.3 - `array_walk($cars[0], function($brand, $key) use($cars) {`

Comment: Hey @pebbl , thanks for that pal! do / while and foreach i have learn't however i will have to look up array_combine and array_walk method in the manual since they are foreign to me. As an amateur that wants to be good, I much appreciate the extra methods for me to learn :)